# shape as drawable is invisible

Tags: android, xml, shapes

Given a shape that is defined in `drawable/red_ring.xml` as

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:thickness="25dp"
    android:useLevel="false">

  <solid
      android:color="#ff0000"/>

  <stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#000000"/>

</shape>
```

and a simple layout

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Hello"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/red_ring" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**The problem with above**: the shape will not show up on the button.

- red_ring as `android:background` works,
- any framework drawable **bitmap** as `android:drawableLeft` also works.

But custom shape as `android:drawableLeft` appears to be ignored

API level is 15

I feel that I am missing something really obvious, but what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

red_ring has no bounds set, thats why its invisible

Comment: Indeed, I had to add

<size
        android:width="15dp"
        android:height="15dp" />

to the shape and this made it work.

Thank you